# Difference in usage between calling runtime.Gosched() and receiving from a channel?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm using an open source package that leverage the `runtime.Gosched()` to wait for a resource to be available. And found it may cause a high CPU usage. The code can be simplified to be like this:

```golang
func wait() {
    for {
        // check if something is available, and return it when available.
        // if size > oldSize {
        //  return buffer[oldSize:size-1]
        // }

        // In my case there's no write to the buffer for quite a long time
        // so that it keep arriving at this Gosched calling
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}

func run() {
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        go wait()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second*20)
}
```

I have observed that it took all the CPU resource available when running the run() function. However, when using a channel, as the following code, there is no such problem.

```golang
func waitForChannel(ch chan struct{}) {
    <- ch
}

func runWithChannel() {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        go waitForChannel(ch)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second*20)
    //close(ch)
}
```

I know that I should use channels, when I want to wait for a resource and yield the current processor. However I can't find an explanation of the difference of waiting for a channel and calling Gosched over and over again. And what's the use case of Gosched, if it's not suitable for this situation.

Comment: What do you think happens if you call "Gosched" but there's no other goroutines that can be scheduled in?

Comment: runtime.Gosched is a **low** **level** function which does nothing except allowing other goroutines to run. Its use is _very_ limited. Your code example is a proper use of Gosched as a tight for-loop doesn't yield the processor but it is nonsensical as it does nothing useful. If any of your goroutines ever has to execute e.g. a tight loop which does not yield the processor, than _adding_ Gosched can help overcomming this "does-not-yield"-problem. Gosched is _never_ used ad hoc.

Comment: I endorse Volker's comment. I will add that since pre-emptive go-routine scheduling was added (Go 1.11?) that uses for Gosched() have virtually disappeared. (BTW it's probably using a lot of CPU only because it's being called a lot.)

Comment: @Volker in my case (the package I'm using) it is to wait until there's new data in a buffer. Actually it's not a tight-loop, in my opinion. Maybe it's just that this package doesn't do the thing in a right way.

Comment: It is impossible to speculate about code we cannot see. Either the package you are using is doing some low level (pseudo) optimization, it was written long time ago when the scheduler's preemption was much worse or it is simply broken.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation for runtime.Gosched says:](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched)

> Gosched yields the processor, allowing other goroutines to run. It does not suspend the current goroutine, so execution resumes automatically.

This suggests that what happens is that you may break out of the `for` loop of one Go routine but immediately enter the `for` loop of another Go routine. Thus the CPU is still busy running a lot of `for` loops, unable to take a breath.

I will usually use a simple `time.Sleep` when waiting for another resource. Even the smallest duration will get the CPU usage of your example down to 0% (says the Task Manager):

```
package main

import "time"

func wait() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1)
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        go wait()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 20)
}
```

Note that you would usually say something like

```
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
```

or some other duration. I just wanted to illustrate that even the smallest timeout will give the CPU air to breathe.

Answer (score 0):

The [runtime.Gosched](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) function yields the processor so that other goroutines can run. It does not suspend the calling goroutine.

> However I can't find an explanation of the difference of waiting for a channel and calling Gosched over and over again.

Receive on a channel suspends the receiving goroutine until a value is available or the channel is closed.

A call to Gosched yields the processor so that other goroutines can run, but it does not suspend the goroutine. The loop in the goroutine continues to spin and consume CPU resources.

> And what's the use case of Gosched, if it's not suitable for this situation.

It's rare that a program needs to call Gosched.

Channel send and receive, mutex lock and unlock, I/O and other operations can yield the processor. These yield points are usually sufficient for an application.

The Gosched call is needed in long running operations that do not otherwise yield the processor. An example is a long running numeric calculation that does not do any I/O.